# Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started - Testcontainers with @ServiceConnection and Spring 3.1.4

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5, spring-boot-testcontainers

I'm trying to update my tests to use the latest support for ***Spring 3.1.4*** for testcontainers, which ***replaces*** the `@DynamicSource` annotation with `@ServiceConnection` as per [here](https://spring.io/blog/2023/06/23/improved-testcontainers-support-in-spring-boot-3-1) .
However, I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: 
Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: 
Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: 
Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started
```

These are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And here my classes:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class FollowshipIT extends BasePostgresConfig {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    ...

}
```

```
public class BasePostgresConfig {

    @Container
    @ServiceConnection
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13.5");

}
```

I tried both with and without keeping an active profile and -test.yml file with DB configs like the one below and annotating my BasePostgresConfig class with @ActiveProfiles("test"), as I had before for my previous configuration, but that didn't work either.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    driver-class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:13.5:///helloTalk
```

Here is the [full code](https://github.com/francislainy/HelloTalk/blob/testcontainers/src/test/java/com/example/hellotalk/functionaltests/FollowshipIT.java) for my application.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works:

```
@Testcontainers
public class BasePostgresConfig {

    @Container
    @ServiceConnection
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres;

    static {
        postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13.5");
        postgres.start();
    }

}
```

Perhaps there could be other ways to achieve this, but for this solution I had to start the container in a static block by calling `postgres.start()`.

About the `@TestContainers` annotation, the tests pass also without it, but better to leave it there so the containers are closed after the test execution.

**UPDATE**

After some further investigation, I've noticed the need to call `postgres.start()` seems to be related to the fact the tests have the `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` annotation, which is used to remove the need for the `@BeforeAll` method to be static.

Comment: This is not how it is supposed to work. As mentioned in the other answer Testcontainers annotation start and stop the container implementation using Container annotation. So, start the container manually is not needed. This solution is mixing two different approaches

Comment: I would be happy to hear of a solution without starting the container. My code has been posted on the question for anyone who would like to experiment with that. If you clone the code and remove the call to start the container, you should be able to see it failing.

Comment: what I mean is your solution should be valid if you use one of the approaches but not both together. The piece of code showing both using Testcontainers/Container annotations and start() call will confuse further readers.

Comment: I understand that, however as of now, only having they both combined is allowing for my tests to pass. I also find it strange, but it's only working this way.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `@Testcontainers` annotation at test class level, which will start and stop container implementations annotated with `@Container`

You can check the Testcontainers JUnit 5 docs https://java.testcontainers.org/quickstart/junit_5_quickstart/

In order to know more about Testcontainers and JUnit 5 integration see https://testcontainers.com/guides/testcontainers-container-lifecycle/

Also, take into account that the following code is not needed

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    driver-class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:13.5:///helloTalk
```

due to PostgreSQLContainer is being used directly. Check more [here](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I get the same error with or without the testcontainers on top of the BasePostgresConfig class, and also with or without  the yml file.